# Can PHPPowerPoint Copy Existing PowerPoint

Tags: php, phppowerpoint

I would like to make a master Powerpoint or .PPTX by copying slides from multiple Powerpoint (PPT) presentations. I would like to give PHPPowerPoint a list of file locations as input and let it create the master PPT or PPTX. Can PHPPowerPoint do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Release 0.3.0 (Sep 22, 2014) includes the the ability to read PowerPoint97 files so it seems like you would be able to do this.

- All releases: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPowerPoint/releases
- Release 0.3.0: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/releases/tag/0.3.0

It seems like you can use code like this:

```
$oReaderPPT = \PhpOffice\PhpPowerpoint\IOFactory::createReader('PowerPoint97');
$oReaderPPT->load('/path/to/my.ppt');
```

From there, you may be able to use a combination of -`>getSlideCount`, `->getSlide`, and `->addSlide`.